# Navigation bar with left and center aligned buttons in html/css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[Example of what the navigation bar should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFpGd.png)

I'm making my first website in html/css and I want to make a fixed navigation bar that can adapt to mobile screens. It should have a left aligned 'home' button and the rest of the buttons are center aligned. How can I make this with HTML/CSS? Thank you!

Here is my code at the moment:

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    margin:0;
  }

  li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    border: 1.5px solid rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.15);
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 40px;
    display: block;
    transition:all 0.3s ease 0s;
    text-align: center;
}

li a:hover {
    color:black;
}


.left-links{
  flex:1 1 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="navBar.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  
<div>
  <ul>
    <div class="left-links">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </div>
    <nav>

      <li><a href="index.html">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="me.html">Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="play.html">Play</a></li>
    </nav>
  </ul>
</div>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by changing `flex:1 1 200px;` to just `flex: 0.5;` under `.left-links` in your css file.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to also tell you to add `display: flex;` to `ul` in your css file as well

Answer (score 0):

I've altered the code a little, but this is how I would tackle it.

By placing each section of links that are related together in a `flex-box` div, and displaying the entire nav element itself as a flex. We can independently address each grouping of links, as well as the nav as a whole.

Adding the `flex-grow` to the `.right-links` will inherit the entirety of the remaining space left from the home button, and adding in `justify-content: center;` centers the `.right-links` in that remaining space. This will work across screen widths and reduces the clutter of using lists when they might not be needed.

Hope this helps!

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    margin:0;
  }
a {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 500;
}

  nav {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    border: 1.5px solid rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.15);
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 40px;
    display: block;
    transition:all 0.3s ease 0s;
    text-align: center;
}

a:hover {
    color:black;
}


.left-links{
  display:flex;
  text-align: left;
}
.right-links{
  justify-content:center;
  flex-grow:1;
  display: flex;
  flex:1 1 200px;
  text-align: left;

}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="navBar.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  
<div>
    <nav>
      <div class="left-links">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="right-links">
        <div>
            <a href="index.html">Work</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="me.html">Me</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="play.html">Play</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
</div>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
   
  </body>
</html>
```